# Flutter - Animated process widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I want to create a process animation widget like this in flutter, which shifts from 1 to 2 with pageview.

[image]

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: checkout this package https://pub.dev/packages/page_view_indicators.

Comment: that looks fine, but how can implement the line which connects those circles ? @VirenVVarasadiya

Comment: you can customise package according to your requirements.

Comment: okay, I will try to implement that and let you know @VirenVVarasadiya

Comment: try out this site you may need to translate this page https://blog.csdn.net/qq_23756803/article/details/98141006

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This can be achieved using the flutter widget Stepper, below is the basic implementation of Stepper Widget

Full article on [Medium here](https://medium.com/flutteropen/flutter-widgets-16-stepper-485ad8d1a248)

```
Widget _tabStep() => Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
    color: PURPLE,
    child: Stepper(
      steps: [
        Step(
          title: Text("First"),
          content: Text("This is our first example."),
        ),
        Step(
          title: Text("Second"),
          content: Text("This is our second example."),
        ),
        Step(
          title: Text("Third"),
          content: Text("This is our third example."),
        ),
        Step(
          title: Text("Forth"),
          content: Text("This is our forth example."),
        ),
      ],
      currentStep: _index,
      onStepTapped: (index) {
        setState(() {
          _index = index;
        });
      },
      onStepCancel: () {
        print("You are clicking the cancel button.");
      },
      onStepContinue: () {
        print("You are clicking the continue button.");
      },
    ),
  );
```